# How to open automounted devices with thunar in gnome shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, notifications, thunar

I'm would like to open automounted devices in Gnome Shell with Thunar, instead of Nautilus. Specifically, from the notification that is shown after a device is mounted.

I thought of editing **/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop** file, but changing `Exec=nautilus --new-window %U` to `Exec=thunar %U` or even to `Exec=/usr/bin/thunar %U` did not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?